# VBA, Microsoft query. Large amount of records, Excel Crashes

Tags: excel, vertica, microsoft-query, vba

Is there any workarounds for importing records ~2 million into excel from vertica database using microsoft query?
I am using microsoft query tool to import data.
I am successfully able to query my database for the smaller tables, larger tables(2 million records) not so much. My excel is crashing.

Anyone have any workarounds or other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Excel can only handle around 1 million records per tab. Or is MS Query filtering the 2 million results and only feeding a subset to Excel?

Comment: Microsoft Power Pivot https://support.office.com/en-us/article/power-pivot-powerful-data-analysis-and-data-modeling-in-excel-a9c2c6e2-cc49-4976-a7d7-40896795d045?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: @JNevill , Its not showing in excel, screen goes white then needs to be restarted. Yes this 1 million records may the issue, not sure if I can split the query into 2 or 3 sheets. Even then performance may suck.

Comment: I think, perhaps, excel isn't the right place to do whatever you are trying to do. Can you filter the data before it hits your spreadsheet? Or create a pivot on the data source so you can drag and drop just the pieces you need?

Answer (score 2):

Excelguy - I think you should consider becoming an SQL-guy ...

Whatever you would do with ~2 million rows in Excel, I'm pretty sure you can do in Vertica. I mean, you won't read millions of rows with your naked eye, but you will apply formulas to them, sum them, etc.

The human eye can consume a few dozen rows - and still make sense of it. Maybe a few more if you make a chart out of the data. But that's it.

I really suggest you explore ways to do in SQL - in the database - whatever you want to do in Excel currently; and then to export the result table - a few rows - to Excel for human consumption.

You will be flabbergasted how much faster everything will work, and be astonished of the new possibilities opening themselves for you ....

If you doubt it - can you sketch what you want to do in Excel?

Cheers -

Marco

Hi Again Excelguy -

Having seen your answer; except for the case that the Oracle table is massive and the Vertica table is a wee sma' one  - you'd be probably better off performing the join in Vertica.

You can consult: 
https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-write-to-a-csv-file-using-oracle-sql-plus/

for how to export the output of an Oracle query to a csv file.

The shortcut is here:

Start SqlPlus, and go:

```
    set colsep ,
    set headsep off
    set pagesize 0
    set trimspool on
    set linesize <number of columns of your Oracle table / Oracle query>
    set numwidth <longest length of your numeric literals>
    spool myoratable.csv
    SELECT * FROM myoratable;
    spool off
    exit
```

Then you can fire `DESC myoratable`  from SqlPlus, and use that output to create a table `myoratable` in Vertica. (I won't go into details with data types for now, cause that's a very long story).

Then, you log on to Vertica, and create the table `myoratable` from what SqlPlus had suggested.

Continue with this:

```
    COPY myoratable
    FROM 
    LOCAL -- this only if the myoratable.csv file is not on the Vertica cluster
    '/full/path/to/your/file/myoratable.csv'
    DELIMITER ','
    DIRECT -- this writes directly to disk and does not fiddle around with Vertica memory too much
    ;
```

From then on, you can just join your `myoratable`with the Vertica table.

Happy playing ...
Marco

Comment: Youre right marco, sigh. Well I wanted to query a few different databases and join the records across databases using some unique key, i really only thought of vba because its somewhat familiar. Sigh quite disappointed right now as i don't think this is possible in excel. Perhaps i can create views in each database which will narrow down the record set, then go to excel.

Comment: @excelguy which dbms'es? Excel will do `join` for long time(very slow), don't do it in Excel.

Comment: @sKwa just vertica and Oracle. sigh wish i knew python or something.

Comment: @excelguy, to perform join for ~1m rows programatically also isn't a good idea. Much more better if you will load data from Oracle to Vertica and will perform join in dbms(or opposite, load from Vertica to Oracle). We can help with data load to Vertica(you can query Oracle directly from Vertica)

Comment: @skwa, interesting idea, if loaded in  one dbms then joined, perhaps could get data quite easily barring a complex set of queries. Great idea.

Comment: @excelguy: you can query Oracle from Vertica with [odbc_loader_package](https://github.com/vertica/Vertica-Extension-Packages/tree/master/odbc_loader_package). I believe you can query Vertica from Oracle with dblink but Im not an expert in Oracle.

Comment: @sKwa , hey skwa, i didnt realize but its not oracles its SQL server 2012. and vertica. Can what you describe above still be done?

Comment: @excelguy It doesn't matter, you can query Vertica directly from MS SQL(read [here](http://www.aodba.com/how-to-create-a-linked-server-from-sql-server-to-hp-vertica/)). Query Vertica => Insert data to MS SQL => join/aggregate data in MS SQL => create final reports in Excel by querying MS SQL(from Excel)